# An internal error occured . Editing functionally may be limited xcode Version 9.4.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode9

I'm getting following error.

> An internal error occured . Editing functionally may be limited

I tried everything which was written on stackoverflow.(reinstalling xcode,cleaning project such sudo commands etc.)but any of them didnt work on me.Then i found log file about problem.I'm waiting for your helps.

Thanks.

> Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool. (Failure reason: Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool failed to launch): Failed to boot device iPhone X (4557BB7A-1EB1-4D22-B37D-3DF63804AEC4, iOS 11.4, Shutdown) for context  toolName = Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool, description =  System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater  deviceType=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-X (Failure reason: Failed to boot iPhone X (4557BB7A-1EB1-4D22-B37D-3DF63804AEC4, iOS 11.4, Shutdown)): Unable to boot device because it cannot be located on disk. (Failure reason: The device's data is no longer present at /Users/burak/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IB Support/Simulator Devices/4557BB7A-1EB1-4D22-B37D-3DF63804AEC4/data.)

[image: Screenshot of my problem]

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?